# The best practice to use Tycho/Maven to remove jars dependencies in Eclipse RCP?

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I'm working one an Eclipse RCP project. Currently we create a `dependencies` plug-in project and put all jars libraries into that project and export all packages. This method will give a huge repo, thus we want to use Tycho/Maven and let it figure out the dependencies for us.

The first approach is removing `dependenciec` project and use [p2-maven-pluging](https://github.com/reficio/p2-maven-plugin) to transform existing jars libraries to p2 format repo. Install all libraries from p2 repos and add required bundle in `Require-Bundle` section in each `MANIFEST.MF`. This is a little bit tedious since in every project having `dependencies` in `Require-Bundle`, I have to manually replace it to corresponding bundle names. And in the end, the project build using Tycho could successfully run, but in Eclipse it gives me `java.lan.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class X`.

I think there are few configuration files, where Tycho depends on some of them and Eclipse depends on the rest, but I'm not sure what it is.

The second approach is removing all jars in `dependencies` project but adding them in `Require-Bundle` or `Import-Package`. However, both won't work since in `Export-Package` section Eclipse will complain these packages are not existed. Thus other projects depends on this `dependencies` project won't find those packages they need, which causing more errors in Eclipse.

Does anyone know the best practice to deal with this issue?

---

Update:

I'm using basically the first approach, but add dependencies in `Import-Package` in each project instead of `Require-Bundle`. This would eliminate the need to specify the specific bundle version, as long as they provide the same API and they are compatible, your application would work. So everytimes I update private p2 repository, I don't need to change `MANIFEST.MF` in each project.

The only `MANIFEST.MF` I need to manually add dependencies in `Require-Bundle` is a library developed by our self. Without it, Tycho won't fetch required dependencies from private p2 repository. If still get `NoClassDefFoundError`, try adding all plugins in Run -> Run Configuration .. -> plug-ins, it may help.

Comment: What is the purpose of creating a project with all the dependent jars? Couldn't you use a feature.xml instead?

Comment: What you are describing is probably doable - but you are doing something wrong. However you description is so vague that we can only guess. Please add more details, e.g. MANIFESTS

Answer (score 0):

I definitely not apply your approach 1, with the mega-plugin of exports. There's a related discussion here: [Handling non-OSGi dependencies when integrating Maven, Tycho and Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22311165/handling-non-osgi-dependencies-when-integrating-maven-tycho-and-eclipse/22882100#22882100)

As a rule, use Import-Package instead of Require-Bundle.

To get bundles will appear in the Export-Package section Eclipse:

- if they are non-Eclipse (maven libraries), then build the project and reference the libraries in the Eclipse runtime section.
- if they are Eclipse dependences, they should be in your workspace or Target Platform.

More generally, it may help for you to define a Target Platform. You can build/deploy all of your locally created plugins into a local p2 repository (see http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/). Then add that p2 site to your Target Platform.